# Remove all the keys from nested object excluding one key in js

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
x = {
    "prop1": {
        "description": "prop1",
        "dataType": "string",
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "description": "sub1",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 12
        },
        "sub2": {
            "description": "sub2",
            "dataType": "integer"
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "description": "input messages",
                "dataType": "boolean",
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "description": "output messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

In the above object, I wanted to remove the keys(description, dataType), also remove the key if it doesn't have any **value** key. the expected output for the above one is as below.

```
y = {
    "prop1": {
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "value" : 12
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
function findValue(obj, string, obj1) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
        obj1[string.substring(1)] = obj.value
        return
    }
    for (var key in obj) {
        findValue(obj[key], [string, key].join("."), obj1)
    }
}

console.log(x);
var x1 = {}
findValue(x, "", x1)
var y = {};

function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
    const lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
      const key = keyPath[i];
      if (!(key in obj)) {
          obj[key] = {}
      }
      obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = { "value": value };
}

Object.keys(x1).forEach(key => {
    const keyPath = key.split('.');
    let value = x1[key];
    if (value != null) {
        this.assign(y, keyPath, value);
    }
});

console.log(y);
```

I did it in a very long way. I first convert my object into a format where each key is the combination of parent and child keys and then converted it into the expected format.

Is there any way to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a general item-handling function. If the item is an object, iterate through its values and recursively call the function, giving a new object in return *if* there are any nested values matching the key. If there are no nested values matching the key, return a unique value (could be a Symbol) indicating to the caller that this value should be removed from the parent object:

```js
const removeThis = Symbol();
const transform = item => {
  if (typeof item !== 'object' || item === null) {
    return item;
  }
  const newEntries = [];
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(item)) {
    if (key === keyToKeep) newEntries.push([key, val]);
    else if (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null) {
      const possibleNewObj = transform(val);
      if (possibleNewObj !== removeThis) {
        newEntries.push([key, possibleNewObj]);
      }
    }
  }
  return newEntries.length
    ? Object.fromEntries(newEntries)
    : removeThis;
};

const obj = {
    "prop1": {
        "description": "prop1",
        "dataType": "string",
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "description": "sub1",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 12
        },
        "sub2": {
            "description": "sub2",
            "dataType": "integer"
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "description": "input messages",
                "dataType": "boolean",
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "description": "output messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    }
};
const keyToKeep = 'value';
console.log(transform(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented by recursively calling an iteration function which check each entry of the given object and remove other keys. I created a function `removeKey` for this.

```
function removeKey(obj, exceptionKey) {
    // loop through the child objects
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // if the entry is an object
            if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                // iterate through the object by recursions
                removeKey(obj[key], exceptionKey);
            } else {
                // if the entry is not an object and not the given key
                if (key !== exceptionKey) {
                    // delete entry
                    delete obj[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var exceptionKey = "value"; // key which need to keep.
removeKey(x, exceptionKey); // x is the initial object
```

Since the object will handle by reference, no need to return the result.

If consoled the `x` after the function `removeKey`, it will give object with only the key specified in `exceptionKey` variable. There's a chance for having empty objects in this result. So I created another function called `removeEmptyObject`.

```
function removeEmptyObject(obj) {
    // loop through the child objects
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // if the entry is an object and empty
            if (Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0 && obj[key].constructor === Object) {
                // delete the entry
                delete obj[key];
            } else if (obj[key].constructor === Object) {
                // if the entry is an object and not empty
                // then loop through the object by recursions
                removeEmptyObject(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through the object and remove empty objects if any. The final result will give the requested object.

```
// remove entries other than the selected key
removeKey(x, exceptionKey);
// remove empty objects
removeEmptyObject(x);
// the final result
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use this recursive code:

```js
const x = {
    "prop1": {
        "description": "prop1",
        "dataType": "string",
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "description": "sub1",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 12
        },
        "sub2": {
            "description": "sub2",
            "dataType": "integer"
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "description": "input messages",
                "dataType": "boolean",
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "description": "output messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    }
};

const reduceObject = object => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
        delete obj.description;
    }
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('dataType')) {
        delete obj.dataType;
    }
    for(let item in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[item] === 'object') obj[item] = reduceObject(obj[item]);
    }
    return obj;
};

console.log(reduceObject(x));
```

**UPDATE**

to remove empty object you can just use this code updated:

```
const reduceObject = object => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
        delete obj.description;
    }
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('dataType')) {
        delete obj.dataType;
    }
    for(let item in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[item] === 'object') {
            obj[item] = reduceObject(obj[item]);
            // remove empty object
            if(Object.keys(obj[item]).length === 0) delete obj[item];
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```